# Spring AMQP : How know message generate AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException

Tags: spring, amqp, spring-amqp

We are a ErrorHandler for the listener. 
We are in Spring AMQP auto mode.

In some case we are some exception throw by the Spring (like serialization problem) and the we receive that exception in ErrorHandler. So, we didn't know what message cause this exception.

It is possible to know that? Like the headers of messages where we put simple functional information.

Tanks's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error handler gets a `ListenerExecutionFailedException` with property `failedMessage` (and cause chain).

Comment: Too simple, I didn't look the type of exception!